# couldn't apply the same classifier configuration (using python code)

Tags: python, configuration, weka

I am trying to classify text documents and I am using the following configuration on weka Gui:

```
weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier -F "weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector -R 1 -W 1000 -prune-rate -1.0 -N 0 -stemmer weka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer -stopwords-handler weka.core.stopwords.Null -M 1 -tokenizer \"weka.core.tokenizers.WordTokenizer -delimiters \\\" \\\\r\\\\n\\\\t.,;:\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\"()?!\\\"\"" -W weka.classifiers.meta.CostSensitiveClassifier -- -cost-matrix "[0.0 5.0; 1.0 0.0]" -S 1 -W weka.classifiers.functions.SMO -- -C 1.0 -L 0.001 -P 1.0E-12 -N 0 -V -1 -W 1 -K "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.PolyKernel -E 1.0 -C 250007"
```

and because I want to automate the process, I've included that command on a python code and add the training and testing file on the command as follows:

```
command_line='java -cp /Users/home/Desktop/weka-3-7-13/weka.jar weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier -t train.arff -T test.arff -F "weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector -R 1 -W 1000 -prune-rate -1.0 -N 0 -stemmer weka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer -stopwords-handler weka.core.stopwords.Null -M 1 -tokenizer \"weka.core.tokenizers.WordTokenizer -delimiters \\\" \\\\r\\\\n\\\\t.,;:\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\"()?!\\\"\"" -W weka.classifiers.meta.CostSensitiveClassifier -- -cost-matrix "[0.0 5.0; 1.0 0.0]" -S 1 -W weka.classifiers.functions.SMO -- -C 1.0 -L 0.001 -P 1.0E-12 -N 0 -V -1 -W 1 -K "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.PolyKernel -E 1.0 -C 250007"> test.txt'

os.system(command_line)
```

I am getting the following error on my code:

> syntax error near unexpected token `?!\"""'

I've tried to remove 'delimiters' assuming that their option is the default as follows:

```
command_line='java -cp /Users/home/Desktop/weka-3-7-13/weka.jar weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier -t train.arff -T test.arff -F "weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector -R 1 -W 1000 -prune-rate -1.0 -N 0 -stemmer weka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer -stopwords-handler weka.core.stopwords.Null -M 1 -tokenizer \"weka.core.tokenizers.WordTokenizer \"" -W weka.classifiers.meta.CostSensitiveClassifier -- -cost-matrix "[0.0 5.0; 1.0 0.0]" -S 1 -W weka.classifiers.functions.SMO -- -C 1.0 -L 0.001 -P 1.0E-12 -N 0 -V -1 -W 1 -K "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.PolyKernel -E 1.0 -C 250007"> test.txt'
os.system(command_line)
```

and it did work but it gave me different results, so is there a way to excuse it without removing 'delimiters' option?
I am not sure how to fix it as I am new to both python and weka .. any help is appreciated.